# Circle equivalent of the line voxel transversal for a 2D grid

Tags: algorithm, 3d, 2d, raytracing, voxel

I am looking for a circle algorithm, similar to what a line (ray) 2D voxel transversal is. I want to use it to populate the voxels that the circle line intersect (not filling it, it is just the outline).
Also, I need to draw it as arc segments (starting in a point angle until the end angle point)
Any ideas?